# droplevels not dropping anything

Tags: r

I am trying to use droplevels.
First I create a subsect of my dataset where the value of attribute Rat must be different from 1 or 5. That value must be a factor. Then, I can see levels are "1", "2", "3", "4" and "5". As I use droplevels() nothing changes. How can I do properly? I wrote this code:

```
chocolate234 <- subset(chocolate, Rat!="1")
chocolate234 <- subset(chocolate234, Rat!="5")
droplevels(chocolate234$Rat)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like most function in r, `droplevels` operates on your data but does not change it. The `droplevels` function returns a factor vector with the levels dropped, but it does not change the original vector. To do that, you need to assign the result of `droplevels` back to the original original vector. Here is an example:

```
# Building an example data.frame
set.seed(1234)
rating <- factor(as.character(sample(1:5, 100, replace = T)))
label <- sample(LETTERS, 100, replace = T) 
example <- data.frame(label = label, Rat = rating)
summary(example$Rat)
  1  2  3  4  5 
 25 26 17 17 15 

# Subsetting the data
example234 <- subset(example, Rat != "1")
example234 <- subset(example234, Rat != "5")
summary(example234$Rat)
  1  2  3  4  5 
  0 26 17 17  0 

# Dropping unused levels
droplevels(example234$Rat)
  [1] 4 4 4 4 2 4 3 4 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 2 2 3 4 2 2 3 4 2 4 2 3 4 3 2 4 2 4
  [38] 3 3 3 4 2 2 4 2 3 3 4 3 2 2 4 3 3 2 2 3 2 2 4
  Levels: 2 3 4
summary(example234$Rat)
  1  2  3  4  5 
  0 26 17 17  0 

# Reassigning the data with dropped levels
example234$Rat <- droplevels(example234$Rat)
summary(example234$Rat)
  2  3  4 
 26 17 17
```

Notice in my example, like your attempt, if you just run `droplevels` on the data, it does not change the underlying data. However, if you assign the results of `droplevels(example234$Rat)` to `example234$Rat`, your underlying data has been properly changed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear explanation!